# Removing specific lines from inside a file in Python

Tags: python, file

I have a list of documents in a file. Basically the TDT2 corpus consisting on both mandarin and english files. I want to keep only the english documents and remove the mandarin ones. Manually doing so would take very long since the file is huge.

The structure looks something like this:

```
<ONTOPIC topicid=20001 level=YES docno=VOA19980630.1800.3165 fileid=19980630_1800_1900_VOA_ENG comments="NO">
<ONTOPIC topicid=20001 level=BRIEF docno=VOM19980220.0700.0559 fileid=19980220_0700_0800_VOA_MAN comments="NO">
<ONTOPIC topicid=20001 level=YES docno=VOM19980220.0700.1159 fileid=19980220_0700_0800_VOA_MAN comments="NO">
```

So I want to remove the files which have a 'MAN' in their fileid. 
How can I do this specific task in Python?

Comment: So these lines are contents of a file and you want to ouput the lines which have 'ENG'? in case I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If lines are not written with `\n` just remove it from the endswith clause. 
This will ignore any files which end with `MAN comments="NO">` and output out the other files.

```
out = open('file2.txt','wb')    
for i in open('file.txt'):
    if i.endswith('MAN comments="NO">\n'):
        pass
    else:
        out.write(i)

out.close()
```

If you are sure 'MAN' will only be part of mandarian ones. Looks a bit cleaner.

```
out = open('file2.txt','wb')    
for i in open('file.txt'):
    if 'MAN' not in i:
        out.write(i)

out.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. However,I just realized some of these file are in English but they don't have an ENG extension. In case I use this, then even those files will get deleted. Some are like this: <ONTOPIC topicid=20084 level=BRIEF docno=NYT19980206.0390 fileid=19980206_1917_2029_NYT_NYT comments="NO"> So this is still an english file but it doesn't contain the NG symbol. In such a case, is possible to do something like if i in (**VOA*,**ABC*)? The stars here refer to wildcard character and VOA, ABC are the beginning keywords of the fileid which I know are English ones.

Comment: try now. It will only ignore MAN files.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. Just another question, if one of the file contains suppose ABC_MAN and not VOA_MAN. In that case, is it better to use if i.endswith('*_MAN comments= "No"< \n")

Comment: or you have other cases like say comments = "YES" you can always qualify them like `i.endswith('MAN comments="NO">\n') or i.endswith('MAN comments="YES">\n')`. I'm not just looking for 'MAN' since it's a very general word and can be a part of your other files also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def start():
    sFile = "source.txt"
    dFile = "results.txt"
    with open(dFile, 'w') as dHandle:
        with open (sFile, "r") as fhandle:
            for fline in fhandle.readlines():
                if "MAN" not in fline:
                    dHandle.write(fline)

start()
```

Comment: this is very general, "MAN" could easily be part of ENG files description etc. It has docno, fileid, anycan contain 'MAN'

Comment: Also `in` is not as efficient as `endswith`

Comment: His question only stated on removing the files which have a 'MAN' in their fileid. Thus, all fileid containing "MAN" will be discarded on results.

Comment: Thanks @vahnevileyes. This worked perfectly too! It removed all the mandarin ones.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks